# Validation Webflux ReactiveMongo

Tags: spring, spring-data-mongodb, reactive

I wanna ask about Webflux using Spring-data-mongoreactive. how you perform checking data exist? I've been search for 3 days but still not found the way.

```
 public Mono<TenantRegistrationModel> registration(TenantRegistrationModel registrationModel1) {
    registrationModel1.beforeRegistration();
    return Mono.just(registrationModel1).flatMap(registrationModel -> {
        TenantEntity tenantEntity = new TenantEntity();
        tenantEntity.setFullName(registrationModel.getFullName());
        tenantEntity.setEmail(registrationModel.getEmail());
        tenantEntity.setCountry(registrationModel.getCountry());
        tenantEntity.setCity(registrationModel.getCity());
        BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        tenantEntity.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(registrationModel.getPassword()));
        tenantEntity.setUpdatedAt(new Date());
        tenantEntity.setCreatedAt(new Date());
        Mono<TenantEntity> tenantEntityMono = this.tenantService.save(tenantEntity);
        return this.tenantRepository.findByEmail(registrationModel.getEmail()).next().doOnNext(tenantEntity1 -> {
            if (tenantEntity1.getEmail() != null)
                throw new ApiExceptionUtils("email already eixst", HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY.value(), StatusCodeUtils.VALIDATION_FAIL);
        }).switchIfEmpty(tenantEntityMono).map(tenantEntity1 -> {
            registrationModel.setId(tenantEntity1.getId());
            return registrationModel;
        });
    });
}
```

I want to validate 2 query from mongoreactive and comparing the result.

Comment: Please provide us with code samples of what you tried until now. That way we can help you more effectively.

Comment: I want to comparing 2 query from mongoreactive and check the data.